# php 5.3.2 and htmlentities flag ENT_XML1

Tags: php-5.3, html-entities

We're using PHP version 5.3.2 with FastCGI under Lighttpd 1.4.26:

```
$ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 -v
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20 with Suhosin-Patch (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 15 2013 17:10:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2009, by mOo
```

I've got a php script that's generating a notice to the Lighttpd web server error log:

```
2013-08-30 14:11:46: (mod_fastcgi.c.2711) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Notice:  
Use of undefined constant ENT_XML1 - assumed 'ENT_XML1' in 
/var/www/request.php on line 719
```

The script at that line is calling htmlentities():

```
htmlentities($xml, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')
```

The documentation for [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) says that the constant ENT_XML1 was added on version 5.4.0, so I'm wondering how version 5.3.2 knows to "assume ENT_XML1" as its default?  Did the 5.3.2 release possibly add that?  It didn't jump out at me in the [PHP5 ChangeLog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

Note: the script does appear to be converting the html entities in the $xml string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you're getting actually means that php doesn't recognize ENT_XML1 as a constant and is therefore converting it into the string 'ENT_XML1'. htmlentities isn't doing what you'd want it to do because you're not passing it the proper flags constants

`htmlentities(ENT_QUOTES | 'ENT_XML1')`

isn't the same as

`htmlentities(ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1)`